# Can I represent arbitrary binary data in WTF-8 (or any extension of UTF-8)?

Tags: utf-8, utf-16

A long time ago, there was a two-byte Unicode encoding UCS-2, but then it was determined that two bytes are sometimes not enough. In order to cram more codepoints into 16 bit, surrogate pairs were introduced in UTF-16. Since Windows started out with UCS-2, it doesn't enforce rules around surrogate pairs in some places, most notably file systems.

Programs that want to use UTF-8 internally have a problem now dealing with these invalid UTF-16 sequences. For this, WTF-8 was developed. It is mostly relaxed UTF-8, but it is able to round-trip invalid surrogate pairs.

Now it seems like it should be possible to relax UTF-8 a bit further, and allow it to represent *arbitrary* binary data, round-tripping safe. The strings I am thinking about are originally 99.9% either valid UTF-8, or almost valid UTF-16 of the kind WTF-8 can stomach. But occasionally there will be invalid byte sequences thrown in.

WTF-8 defines [generalized UTF-8](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/#generalized-utf8) as:

> an encoding of sequences of code points (not restricted to Unicode scalar values) using 8-bit bytes, based on the same underlying algorithm as UTF-8. It is a strict superset of UTF-8 (like UTF-8 is a strict superset of ASCII).

Would generalized UTF-8 allow me to store *arbitrary* 32 bit sequences, and thus arbitrary data? Or is there another way, such as a unicode escape character? Things I don't want to do are base64 encoding or percent-encoding, since I want to leave *valid* unicode strings unchanged.

Standard disclaimer: I encountered this problem a couple times before, but right now it is an academic question, and I'm just interested in a straight answer how to do this. There is no XY problem :-)

Comment: 32-bit in UTF-8 is impossible. UTF-8 (original) can encode 31-bit data. 21 bit are used for Unicode (but you have other free combination on lower values. Do you want to distribute as text, or just an "intern" way to save binary data with text?

Comment: I'm just looking at an internal way to store data that is usually UTF-8 (or UTF-16), but might be invalid. Like Linux or Windows file system data. It is important to be able to round-trip. And it would be nice if valid strings are unchanged (otherwise I could just e.g. base64 everything). For display, I would just drop or replace the invalid characters.

Comment: You can use Python idea: you use surrogate codepoints (D800-DFFF) to put binary data. It invalid to put them in UTF-8, and if you have single surrogate (so not pairs), just encode both as bytes. So you have UTF-8 and binary on same encoding. Else: just consider that UTF-8 (original) can encode 31-bit integers. codepoint <-> UTF-8 is well defined (as codepoint, so numbers, not as Unicode semantic). Just decoders should discard data in surrogates (and overlong sequences, and values above 10FFFFh (valid on original UTF-8).

Comment: The spec seems to be specifically aimed at potentially malformed UTF-16. So if you can represent every code point between U+0000 through U+FFFF, including invalid ones, then two of those can represent every possible 32-bit value.  It might not be a very efficient encoding (haven't looked into that) but it should work I guess.

Comment: @tripleee A specification is always specifical. :)

Comment: A [foolproof way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200831-00/?p=104142) to roundtrip *arbitrary bytes* through standard UTF-8 without any data loss (but may not *visually* appear like you want for non-ASCII characters) would be to convert the bytes to Unicode using [codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), then encode the Unicode to UTF-8.  You can then reverse the process by decoding UTF-8 to Unicode and then converting Unicode to codepage 437.  Codepage 437 maps all 256 bytes to valid Unicode codepoints.

Comment: Or, you could simply treat arbitrary bytes 0x00..0xFF as-if they are Unicode codepoints U+0000..U+00FF and encode them to/from UTF-8 accordingly.